# Regex match and replace with delimiters included in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I match and replace some pattern but include the delimiters in my match?

I'd like to add a `<strong>` HTML tag around the these two delimiters `$` and `USD`.

From this

```
"Buy today for $ 100 USD"
```

To this

```
"Buy today for <strong>$ 100 USD</strong>"
```

The price could be either `100`, `100.99`, or even `1,000.99`.

I'm trying this but it doesn't work.

```
someString.replace(/(\$)(.*?)(USD)/, '<strong>$1</strong>');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply place the delimiters inside of the main capturing group instead of separating them into three groups.

```
var r = 'Buy today for $ 100 USD'.replace(/(\$.*?USD)/, '<strong>$1</strong>')
console.log(r); //=> "Buy today for <strong>$ 100 USD</strong>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [**function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) to return the replace

```
someString.replace(/(\$[ ]?[\d\.\,]+[ ]?USD)/, 
          function(x){
              return '<strong>' + x + '</strong>';
          }
);
```

Comment: While this works, I prefer @hwnd for simplicity unless you can provide some reason why this is better.

Comment: @Pier it is similar to the accepted solution. I prefer the one you have accepted. but I always get confused using that :)